# Improve query response time using Spark x Dataproc

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am having a little challenge here trying to improve the performance on my query. I am reading my bigquery table using sparking and then querying it to retrieve some values. The bigquery table is 34M rows, 30 cols (10 are strings, 5 integers, the rest floats), 6gb

I have a dataproc cluster with 20 nodes of N1-4core / 16gb VM.

Below is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('1.2. BigQuery Storage & Spark SQL - Python')\
  .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar') \
  .getOrCreate()


spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)

table = "pokerservers.parquetdb.DB19022023_flop"
df_query = spark.read \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("table", table) \
  .load()

df_query.createOrReplaceTempView("df_query_view")

df_query_view = spark.sql("""
FROM df_query_view
WHERE best_hand_flop = 'ONE_PAIR'
AND prob >= 0.9
AND prob <= 1.1
AND proba_win_flop >= 0.87
AND proba_win_flop >= 0.91
AND proba_draw_flop >= -0.01
AND proba_draw_flop <= 0.01
AND actions_preflop = 'rre'
AND actions_flop = 'e' 
AND actions_turn = '-'
AND actions_river = '-' 
AND checker_flop >= -0.01
AND checker_flop <= 0.01
AND Pair = 0 
AND Three = 0
AND Four = 0
AND Straight = 1
AND Colors = 1
AND Highcard = 13
AND Low = 1
AND Bottom = 1 
AND Middle = 0
AND Top = 1
AND StraightDirect = 1 
""").cache()

df_query_view.cache()
avg_call = df_query_view.select(mean('Call')).collect()[0][0]
print(avg_call)
```

So when the query find a match, the response time is decent (<1 sec), even though I was hoping to get something faster as the table is not gigantic.

But when the query does not find a match, then the response time is catastrophic, 30 to 60 secs. I cannot deal with such latency because in case there is no match I need to fallback fast to another solution.

I did not see much improvement when adding more nodes to my cluster. So at this point I am not sure how to deal either with bigger tables or just handle the "no match" case.

Another interesting point. Looks like loading the dataframe and printing it is actually quite fast, but the slow part really happens when trying to calculate the average value.

What would you suggest?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Can u share a execution plan? Because looks like there is issue happen in predicate pushdown in big query. I suggest just make some checking before make calculation.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: You have many row filters, I'd check the driver log to verify that they are all pushed down to the BigQuery Read API